# Operator <= cannot be applied to double in if statement

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, math, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

I have an `if` statement as follows

```
if (1 <= value <= 20)
{

}
```

`value` is a `double`.

however I get an error which says that "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'"

Is there a way around this error?

Comment: `if (1 <= value && value <= 20)` **READ c# DOCS**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't allow you to do this.

Do like this:

```
if (1 <= value && value <= 20)
```

The problem is not the `double`, problem is your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You:

```
if (1 <= value <= 20)
{

}
```

That is interpreted as

```
(1 <= value) <= 20
```

so first 1 will be compared with `value` and it will be determined if the former is "less than or equal" the latter. That gives a boolean. Then that boolean, True or False, is compared with `<=` to `20`. But you cannot ask if True/False is less than or equal `20`, in C#.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you can not check two expressions without Combining them.

**Solution :** i think you want to check whether `value` is in beteween `1 and 20`

You can Use Logical AND `&&` operator for checking this

Try This:

```
if (value >= 1 && value <= 20)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`1 <= value evaluates out to be bool` (**false if value is less than 1 and true otherwise**).

So it evaluates out to be `(true <= 20) or (false <=20)` and error states clearly that you cannot use operator `<=` to compare bool and double.

You need and (&&) operator to do comparison:

```
if (1 <= value && value <= 20)
{
}
```

Comment: Do I really need to? Your first answer was wrong. you learnt from other answers to post a better one.

Comment: @L.B - I immediately notice an issue in the code after posting. So, i delete it to add more value to the answer but i think you didn't like this. No issues.

Comment: So, i guess you will downvote other posts as well since they are more or less pointing to same.

Comment: No, they are correct since they were posted. On the other hand I'll upvote *Jeppe Stig Nielsen*'s answer.

Comment: I just can't change your ideology dude. Do whatever you feel correct. I know myself that why i deleted it. And Jeppe posted it after my answer, so as per your ideology he might have copied it. Isn't it? Have a great day :)

Comment: Great that you don't take it personally.